# How to enter home address so that Siri recognizes it and can direct me home

Tags: iphone, siri

It asks for me to touch my name and then there is no place to put it. I added it as a note on the contact page but this does not work.

Answer (score 7):

Siri knows who you are and where you live based on an contact card in your Contacts application that you keep up to date for yourself.

Open the Contacts application on your iPhone. Add yourself as a contact. In the address section add an address and set the type to `home`. Save the contact information.

Open the Settings application a go to General -> Siri. In that settings page there's a field that says `My Info` -- click on that field and select your contact entry from your Contacts application.

Now when you ask Siri to find a route home for you, it will use the `home` address saved in the contact that you said was you.

You can add other places to this contact card and Siri will recognize them like `work`. You can also set up relationships in this card. For example: if you create a contact card for your spouse, you can in your contact card link to this other card as a relationship with type `spouse` or `wife` or `husband`. Now when you Siri to "Call my spouse" it will use this relationship in your contact card to determine who your "spouse" is and what numbers are available to be called.

Answer (score -3):

Just go in to your contacts find you and go to home and enter your address and siri will know it :)

Comment: How does this differ from or improve other answers?